# Possible to use wildcards with CALL in CMD?

Tags: command-line

I have a situation where I would like to be able to run as few as one or many batch files from another batch file, but CALL will not accept wildcards to allow me to do so. All the called batch files will have similar names, but I tried it earlier today and it failed to work. I'm just wondering how to go about it, with plain CMD commands.

Comment: You can use the FOR command or FORFILES command to find all files in a folder and do something with them, such as running them. I don't have the time to write you a proper answer now though, but google will help you out with either commands and SuperUser has enough on it too. ForFiles can work with masks, and find files based on the date they were created, whereas for is easier to do something with files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the FOR command to loop over each child batch file.

`FOR %%B IN sub*.bat DO CALL %%B`

> [For - Loop through files - Windows CMD - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
>
> Conditionally perform a command on several files.
>
> ```
> Syntax
>       FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command
>
> Key
>    set         : A set of one or more files, separated by any standard delimiter.
>                  Wildcards can be used.
>
>    command     : The command to carry out, including any command-line parameters.
>
>    %%parameter : A replaceable parameter:
>                  e.g. in a batch file use %%G 
>                       (on the command line %G)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Although wildcards can be used, an alternative method of processing
>   files is to let FOR /F process the output of the command 'DIR /b' This
>   can be useful when you want to use DIR options like sorting.